# How to get the JSON response from the Greenhopper REST API in Gadget?

Tags: json, rest, jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I am not able to get the response from the GreenHopper REST API for the url http://:2990/jira/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprints/1 through my Gadget application.

I able to get the following output when I try it from Browser, Below is the Output.

```
 {"sprints":[{"id":1,"name":"Sprint 1","closed":false}],"rapidViewId":1}
```

My Code snippet to retrive the sprint details in Gadget is :

```
args: {
     key: "sprints",
    ajaxOptions: function () {
    return {                                
        url: "/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprints/1",
           };
     }
 }
```

Can anybody sugget me how to get the JSON Response from greenhopper REST API for a JIRA dashboard.

I am getting following Exception in Server:

```
 [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 [talledLocalContainer] 2013-04-25 15:26:58,985 http-2990-11 ERROR admin 926x5323x1            dggnll 172.27.186.82 /rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprints/1      

 [common.error.jersey.ThrowableExceptionMapper] Uncaught exception thrown by REST service
 [talledLocalContainer] javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
 [talledLocalContainer]   at   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
 [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the right URL so maybe the sprint doesn't exist or you don't have permission to view it? Also, try using the Developer Workbox add-on and the REST API browser to test these kind of methods.